# pyspark dataframe add values if not exists

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a below dataframe which gets overritten whenever the pipeline runs and it adds new column with the date of run with counts per table.

current code:

```
d = {'ab' : 400, 'def': 678}
mapping_expr = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*d.items())])
time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d")
df = df.withColumn(time, mapping_expr.getItem(col("tbl_name")))
```

df:

```
tbl_name 2019_07_24 2019_07_25
ab        123         456
def       234         567
```

how can i change this code to add new table name e.g. tbl_name as hig if that gets added in future.

df:

```
tbl_name 2019_07_24 2019_07_25 2019_09_27
ab        123         400        233
def       234         678        344
hig                              56
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this helps :

```
valuesA = [('ab',123,456),('def',234, 567)]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(valuesA,['tbl_name', '2019_07_24', '2019_07_25'])
+--------+----------+----------+
|tbl_name|2019_07_24|2019_07_25|
+--------+----------+----------+
|      ab|       123|       456|
|     def|       234|       567|
+--------+----------+----------+

valuesB = [('ab',233,), ('def', 344,), ('hig',56,)]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(valuesB,['tbl_name1', '2019_09_27'])

+---------+----------+
|tbl_name1|2019_09_27|
+---------+----------+
|       ab|       233|
|      def|       344|
|      hig|        56|
+---------+----------+


final_df = df2.join(df1, df2.tbl_name1 == df1.tbl_name, how='full').drop("tbl_name")


+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|tbl_name1|2019_09_27|2019_07_24|2019_07_25|
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|      hig|        56|      null|      null|
|       ab|       233|       123|       456|
|      def|       344|       234|       567|
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: thanks preetham, if i add new entry on the same date, it will fail :/

Comment: True, but can be played around using different joins itseems !!